# Air App / AS3 - Load all images from folder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I need to load all images in one folder. How I can do that? 
I have to create selector, but not the system one. Thats why
I want to load all pic from folder ( it can be system selector for folder ).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What I think I understand you are asking:  How to give a list of files in a `DropDownList`?

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:ArrayCollection id="files" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:initialize>
    <![CDATA[
        var folder:File = new File("/path/to/folder/");
        for each(var file:File in folder.getDirectoryListing()) {
            files.addItem(file.nativePath);
        }
    ]]>
</s:initialize>

<s:VGroup>
    <s:DropDownList dataProvider="{files}" width="300" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Comment: I'm using pure AS3. I need to load all pic from selected folder or let to multiple select. I'm not gonna create the DropDownList, but something like GridView. But thanks for help.

Comment: thanks, I found answer, I just gonna use FileReferenceList :)